# handling bluetooth spp pairing request thru app

Tags: android, bluetooth

My android application is in blueotooth SPP server mode and listening for client devices,
my application knows the passcode required for pairing of that devices.

My question is, 
Is it possible to handle pairing request through application.
Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 0):

No - because from a security point of view it is important for the user to be aware of pairing. The idea is that devices are paired and bonded once, then onwards connections happen automatically initiated by applications without need for re-pairing (or user intervention)

Comment: But then Android can always force these methods to show some confirmation popup right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do pairing through application. I did pairing in my application.
for this you have to made IBluetooth interface object accessible by this way:

```
IBluetooth mBluetoothService;
Field fie = Class.forName(bluetoothAdapter.getClass().getName()).getDeclaredField("mService");
fie.setAccessible(true);
mBluetoothService = (IBluetooth) fie.get(bluetoothAdapter);
```

By using this object you can pair with device using IBluetooth interface functions.
(normal Sequence for Auto Pairing)::

```
mBluetoothService.setPin(deviceAddress, PIN);
mBluetoothService.setTrust(deviceAddress);
mBluetoothService.createBond(deviceAddress);
mBluetoothService.setPairingConfirmation(deviceAddress, false);
mBluetoothService.cancelPairingUserInput(deviceAddress);
```

By using those function you can pair with any BT device programmatically.